# Why can I only write ONE item in my Resource.resx file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, resources

I thought I am writing 10 file extensions and their related Icons as Bitmap into a resource file within a for loop. The odd thing is that only the last file extension with its Icon is written into the Resource.resx file. Somehow the next file extension in the loop is overwriting the previous one, but WHY ? I thought a resource is sort of a dictionary with key/value pair where I can add as much as I want just as I do in the Resource designer...

What do I wrong?

My code:

```
private void AddDocument()
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;

            DialogResult result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fileDialog.FileNames.Length; i++)
                {
                    string absoluteFilePath = fileDialog.FileNames.GetValue(i).ToString();
                    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(absoluteFilePath);
                    String fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(absoluteFilePath);

                    Bitmap gdiImage;

                    Document doc = new Document();
                    doc.DocumentData = file;
                    doc.DocumentName = fileDialog.SafeFileNames.GetValue(i).ToString();


                    if (TryIsFileExtensionExisting(fileExtension, out gdiImage))
                    {
                        // Filetype was saved before => Convert GDI Bitmap to wpf BitmapImage
                        doc.DocumentTypeImage = gdiImage.ConvertGDIImageToWPFBitmapImage();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BitmapImage wpfImage;
                        // Filetype is new => get Bitmap out of the Icon
                        Icon icon = IconFromFilePath(absoluteFilePath);
                        Bitmap bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();
                        wpfImage = bitmap.ConvertGDIImageToWPFBitmapImage();
                        doc.DocumentTypeImage = wpfImage;

                        // Save bitmap to resource
                        using (ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter("TBM.Resource"))
                        {
                            writer.AddResource(fileExtension, bitmap);
                            writer.Generate();
                        }
                    }                    

                    DocumentList.Add(doc);
                }
                _documentService.AddDocumentsToPeriod(DocumentList, _parentId);
            }
        }

        private bool TryIsFileExtensionExisting(String fileExtension, out Bitmap wpfImage)
        {
            DictionaryEntry entry;
            using (ResXResourceReader reader = new ResXResourceReader ("TBM.Resource"))
            {
                entry = reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                                        .Where(x => x.Key.ToString()
                                        .Equals(fileExtension, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                                        .FirstOrDefault();
            };            

            wpfImage = entry.Value as Bitmap;
            return entry.Key != null; 
        }

        private Icon IconFromFilePath(string filePath)
        {
            Icon result = null;
            try
            {
                result = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filePath);
                //'# swallow and return nothing. You could supply a default Icon here as well
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
       using (ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter("TBM.Resource"))
       {
           writer.AddResource(fileExtension, bitmap);
           writer.Generate();
       }
```

Each time you create a new writer object and write to it.  But you don't have the creation of the writer object read from the old file.  So you overwrite every time.  You should be able to use a different constructor and solve your problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcewriter.aspx

Comment: So everytime I create a new writer instance I create a new Resource FILE ? That would explain the behavior... Thus I created the writer outside the for loop but then I have the problem that inside the loop I also create a ResXResourceReader to read some stuff and then I can ot access the file twice which leads to a InvalidOperationException as the file is already accessed by another process. How does the Stream param in the Ctor help me here?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do this if you want to read from the file at the same time you are writing to it.... that would seem a bad code smell to me.

Comment: ok problem solved. If the file extension does not exist in the Resource.Resx I dont write like before to the Resource file rather I write to a temporary Dictionary<String,Bitmap> and after the for loop I once open a ResxResourceWriter and dump the temporary stuff into the real Resource file :) I should also not use the Generate within a for loop just after it...